# Ошибка в построении auc-roc

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, kaggle

Имеются [данные](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dont-overfit-ii/data).

Код:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor as rfr
from scipy import stats
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
%matplotlib inline

df_train = pd.read_csv('D:\TITAN\Kaggle\Don`t overfit/train.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('D:\TITAN\Kaggle\Don`t overfit/test.csv')

colmnstodrop = ['id']
x1= df_test.drop(colmnstodrop, axis=1)

ColumnsToDrop = ['target', 'id']
x=df_train.drop(ColumnsToDrop, axis=1)
y=df_train['target']

from sklearn import tree
clf1 = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()
clf1 = clf1.fit(x, y)


from sklearn import svm
clf2 = svm.SVC(gamma='scale')
clf2 = clf2.fit(x, y)

r1=clf1.predict(x1)
r2=clf2.predict(x1)

import sklearn.metrics as me
me.roc_auc_score(x, r1, average='micro', sample_weight=None, max_fpr=None)
```

> ValueError: continuous-multioutput format is not supported

Что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При использовании `superwised learning` (обучение с учителем), для того чтобы оценить модель, сравнивают предсказанные значения с истинными - заранее известными значениями.

Соответственно для того чтобы посчитать метрики ваших моделей придётся разделить `train` dataset (для которого заведомо известны значения в столбце `target`) на две части - обучающую и тестовую. Для обучения будет использоваться только обучающая выборка, а для оценивания модели только тестовая.

Если использовать для оценки модели строки, которые модель уже видела при обучении, то есть ненулевая вероятность получить точность предсказаний - 100% для этих данных, но совершенно непонятно как поведет себя эта модель на новых, незнакомых ей данных. Этот эффект называется - ["Data Leakage"](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/).

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import svm

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df_train.drop(ColumnsToDrop, axis=1), 
    df_train["target"],
    test_size=0.2,
    random_state=42)

clf1 = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()
clf1 = clf1.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf2 = svm.SVC(gamma='scale')
clf2 = clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred1 = clf1.predict(X_test)
y_pred2 = clf2.predict(X_test)
```

Метрики:

```
In [15]: me.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred1, average='micro', sample_weight=None, max_fpr=None)
Out[15]: 0.5285714285714286

In [16]: me.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred2, average='micro', sample_weight=None, max_fpr=None)
Out[16]: 0.5
```

---

Демонстрация эффекта утечки данных - будем делать предсказания для 10% данных из **обучающей** выборки:

```
In [27]: idx = X_train.sample(frac=0.1).index

In [28]: me.roc_auc_score(y_train.loc[idx], clf1.predict(X_train.loc[idx]), average='micro')
Out[28]: 1.0
```

Точность предсказаний для данных, на которых модель обучалась - 100%, а для новых, невиденных ранее данных ~ 53%:

```
In [29]: me.roc_auc_score(y_test, clf1.predict(X_test), average='micro')
Out[29]: 0.5285714285714286
```

Answer (score 2):

[Из официальной документации](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html):

> ```
> sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score(
>      y_true,     # <---- NOTE !!!
>      y_score, 
>      average=’macro’, 
>      sample_weight=None, 
>      max_fpr=None)
> ```

**Parameters:**

> `y_true` : array, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_classes]
>
> True binary labels or binary label indicators.
>
> `y_score` : array, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_classes]
>
> Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive
>   class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions (as
>   returned by “decision_function” on some classifiers). For binary
>   y_true, y_score is supposed to be the score of the class with greater
>   label.

Вы передали `x` вместо `y_true` (`y_test`) в качестве первого параметра.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то y_true, это "ответы" из "train". y_score это данные предиката. Т.е. в моем случае это "y" и "r1"/"r2" соответственно. Но ведь в таком случае я сопоставляю  обученность на правильных ответах с правильными ответами. Результатом естественно становится 1.
Я не понимаю как мне проверить правильность моего предиката и построить на основе этой правильности auc-roc по различным методам.