# Поиск оптимального значения внутри цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Есть конструкция:

```
for ts in [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7]:
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xnp, ynp, test_size=ts)
    for p in [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,50,100,150,200]:
        for k in [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,50,100,150,200]:
            for n in [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,50,100,150,200]:



                print (n, p ,k, ts)

                clf3 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=None, min_samples_split=n, random_state=0)
                scores3 = cross_val_score(clf3, X, y, cv=k)
                print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores3.mean(), scores3.std() * 2))

                clf4 = RandomForestClassifier (n_estimators=p, max_depth=None,min_samples_split=n, random_state=0)
                scores4 = cross_val_score(clf4, X, y, cv=k)
                print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores4.mean(), scores4.std() * 2))                   

                clf5 = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=p, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=n, random_state=0)
                scores5 = cross_val_score(clf5, X, y, cv=k)
                print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores5.mean(), scores5.std() * 2))


                clf7 = svm.SVC(gamma='scale')
                scores7 = cross_val_score(clf7, X, y, cv=k)
                print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores7.mean(), scores7.std() * 2))

                clf8 = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=p)
                scores8 = cross_val_score(clf8, X,y, cv=k)
                print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores8.mean(), scores8.std() * 2))
```

В данной конструкции пытаюсь перепробовать различные значения количества деревьев, размер выборки, количество кросс-валидаций...

Вопрос:
Как/(каким образом) организовать  **поиск** и **наглядный вывод** наиболее оптимальной совокупности значений p,k,n,ts (на текущий момент это делаю я, просматривая весь print)?
Единственное что мне приходит в голову - заполнять новый датафрейм этими данными и осуществлять обозначенный поиск внутри него.

Comment: Чем характеризуется оптимальная совокупность?

Comment: Наивысшими показателями в данном случае кросс-валидации. В дальнейшем показатели будут использоваться  в создании предиката на основе оптимальных показателей оптимального метода.
Вот исходник https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017954/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-auc-roc
там указано соревнование каггла.

Comment: Сохраняйте отдельно максимальный показатель с соответствующими входными данными и выводите в конце этого четырехатажного цикла.

Comment: Так вот я и спрашиваю КАК его найти в этом цикле.

Comment: Если я правильно понял ваши объяснения, то ваши показатели хранятся в переменных ``scoresX``. Или где?

Comment: scoresX отображает % правильности на кросс-валидации. В теле цикла перебираются все возможные p,k,n,ts. Я вот и хочу узнать, при каком одном из всего цикла наборе (p,k,n,ts) scoresX является максимальным. При этом стоит заметить, что scoresX это проверка различных моделей.
К примеру:
2 2 2 0.1
Accuracy: 0.61 (+/- 0.11)
Accuracy: 0.45 (+/- 0.10)
Accuracy: 0.50 (+/- 0.02)
Accuracy: 0.64 (+/- 0.00)
Accuracy: 0.61 (+/- 0.06)

-----------------
4 2 150 0.1
Accuracy: 0.63 (+/- 0.75)
Accuracy: 0.48 (+/- 0.81)
Accuracy: 0.50 (+/- 0.87)
Accuracy: 0.72 (+/- 0.48)
Accuracy: 0.71 (+/- 0.65)

Comment: Ну так заведите переменную для максимального значения scoreX и как-только очередной scoreX превысит имеющийся максимум, сохраняйте новый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. то, что вы собираетесь сделать уже давно реализовано в SciKit-Learn - [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).
2. непонятно для чего нужен самый внешний цикл по переменной `ts` - вы все равно не используете переменные `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test` внутри циклов.

Учитывая все сказанное выше можно сделать приблизительно так:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import (
    RandomForestClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier)
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xnp, ynp, test_size=0.2)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('clf', 
     RandomForestClassifier(
        n_estimators=100, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=2))
])

param_grid = [
   {
    "clf": [RandomForestClassifier(), ExtraTreesClassifier()],
    "clf__n_estimators": [100, 250, 500],
    "clf__max_depth": [None, 5, 10, 20],
    "clf__min_samples_split": [2, 3, 5]
   },
   {
    "clf": [AdaBoostClassifier()],
    "clf__n_estimators": [100, 250, 500],
   }
]

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, 
                    n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
res = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        "mean_test_score": grid.cv_results_["mean_test_score"],
        "mean_fit_time": grid.cv_results_["mean_fit_time"]})
      .join(pd.io.json.json_normalize(grid.cv_results_["params"]).add_prefix("param_"))
)
print(f"best score: {grid.best_score_}")
print(f"best params: {grid.best_params_}")
print("*" * 80)
print(res)
```

**NOTE:** данный код не тестировался, поэтому он может содержать ошибки...

Comment: Я хотел бы уточнить про состав param_grid, поскольку при выполнении куска кода, Ada Boost ругается на количество эстиматоров, 
также уточнить про gs в данной следующей строке : 
_score": gs.cv_results_
Если это GridSearch as sv, то выполнение кода выдает 
type object 'GridSearchCV' has no attribute 'cv_results_'

Comment: @Eugene_Venev, gs надо поменять на grid. А что за ошибка с AdaBoost?

Comment: ValueError: Invalid parameter max_depth for estimator AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME.R', base_estimator=None,
          learning_rate=1.0, n_estimators=50, random_state=None). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.